# Flow - Creating a "one or the other" property

Tags: javascript, flowtype, union-types

I'm trying to create a type for an object which has has base properties, and a 'one or the other' property. I've attempted using **union** and **intersection** types to achieve this, but my knowledge is limited and I can't seem to figure it out.

I was hoping flow could see the first property and infer that the other property shouldn't be allowed (currently I cant even get flow to allow either).

My attempt:

```
type Base = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

type Teacher = Base & {
    teacherId: number,
}

type Student = Base & {
    studentId: number
}

type Person = Student | Teacher;

const person: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
    studentId: 000,
    teacherId: 111
}

console.log(person.age); // Works

console.log(person.studentId); // Fails?
console.log(person.teacherId); // Fails?
```

[Try It](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFAEgB2cC2EAXFAsAE4CWOA5gDQZRRZw3FQ4Cu+ARhORgC+GDKEhQAKhDgBjABb8oqeEigAydNmDT5-AJIATEl178GwpqPDQAysE4GIOYEtiJoGzFjIOnwQ8bcfALCVuIACvwIAPY4rna+zlAAPpI6CuQA3CIysWRQkOQxOCSRRbGuXniEJABEAFLRcji1DEwsbCQATAAMbcw+js4BUD1j-VjashkjAIzzQjl50QA2EAB0K9E0ABSFxeusEACUmVAA9OdQAOrR5ADWCEs4MWub23tRseuDfoanFyuADE4JQVggAPwYXIvVYbLa7fbfKa6cj-M6XKAgsGQoA)

Comment: Add your code as text to the post, and format it to code using the formatting tools provided by the editor.

Comment: But the point is to demonstrate Flow's output?

Comment: Questions must not depend on external resources, with a broken link the question is worth of nothing to the future readers.

Comment: I don't really see the issue. Plenty of questions rely on Codesandbox etc. A quick google shows questions with Flow.org links still working perfectly fine from 2017.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: My question does include the shortest code necessary. Can you point me to the rule disallowing external links?

Comment: It's your question, you do what you want with it ...

Answer (score 0):

Objects are currently inexact by default in Flow (though the team has indicated that this behavior can change). This means that the typing

```
const teacher: Teacher = {
  name: 'Alexa',
  age: 41,
  teacherId: 2,
  studentId: 3
}
```

is completely valid since it has the three required properties `name`, `age`, and `teacherId`. See [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) for more info.

To get Flow to warn against additional properties, you will want to use exact objects (denoted with `{| ... |}`). Flow will now complain about using both `studentId` and `teacherId`.

```
type Base = {|
    name: string,
    age: number
|}

type Teacher = {|
    ...Base,
    teacherId: number,
|}

type Student = {|
    ...Base,
    studentId: number
|}

type Person = Student | Teacher;

const person: Person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
    studentId: 000,
    teacherId: 111
} // Fails
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwD4CgCQA7OAWwgC4oFgAnASzwHMAaLKKHOO0qPAV0ICMIlLBgC+WLKEhQAKhDgBjABaCoqTMxZQAdDvhImOYHKWCAkgBMyPfoKaiNE8NADKwbuYh5gq9Nk3bdRAgDCndPYAsrXgEhe0cpAAVBBAB7PB9XMK8oDBljZUoAbnF5NIooSEpUvDIkqrSfNFwCYjIAIgApFMU8NqYWNg4yACYABn7WUI8vSKhR+YnDfLNLKABGDawRIA)